# Opening big files above 30 mb app gets stuck in android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I open big files(document) in third party app above 30 mb file app gets stuck - can anyone help me out of this?

I use dependency service from Xamarin.Forms for opening the file and in Android I have implemented this code:

```
public void OpenFile(File fileToOpen)
{
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(fileToOpen);
    var intent = new Intent();
    var mime = IOUtil.GetMimeType(uri.ToString());

    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mime);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    _context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What kind of a big file are you talking about here!? is it a document or a video please specify what exactly are you trying to achieve in your question

Answer (score 0):

**If your android phone's system version is android 7.0.**

You need to notice that,in 7.0, Android has enhanced access to files. File access must be fileProvider.

```
fileType = fileType.toLowerCase();
Uri uri = null;
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileProvider", new File(filePath));
}else {
    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
}
intent.setDataAndType(uri, getMap(fileType));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

However,if your three party app does not support the way file permissions are turned on 7.0, it still will error.

So,you can try this rogue method(^-^).***Skip its verification and continue using the 6.0 method***

```
public static void openFileEx(String filePath, String fileType, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 // Judging the version is greater than or equal to 7.0
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
       StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    }
    Uri data = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
    intent.setDataAndType(data, getMap(fileType));
    Toast.makeText(context, "uri:" + data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    context.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

More info about code's getMap method

```
public static String getMap(String key) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("rar", "application/x-rar-compressed");
    map.put("jpg", "image/jpeg");
    map.put("zip", "application/zip");
    map.put("pdf", "application/pdf");
    map.put("doc", "application/msword");
    map.put("docx", "application/msword");
    map.put("wps", "application/msword");
    map.put("xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    map.put("et", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    map.put("xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    map.put("ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    map.put("html", "text/html");
    map.put("htm", "text/html");
    map.put("txt", "text/html");
    map.put("mp3", "audio/mpeg");
    map.put("mp4", "video/mp4");
    map.put("3gp", "video/3gpp");
    map.put("wav", "audio/x-wav");
    map.put("avi", "video/x-msvideo");
    map.put("flv", "flv-application/octet-stream");
    map.put("", "*/*");

    return map.get(key.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply@john but I think there is no issue of android version because already small files are opening.Problem is with the big files